# Does best buy offer a SPARQL endpoint / does it support RDF and/or SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, best-buy-api

There is some mention of support for RDF / SPARQL by best buy (see https://twitter.com/LearningSPARQL/status/294082772836941825). However the page is outdated and i cannot find anything about it in the dev documentation.

Comment: I am really curious why this question is down voted. If you do so, please leave a remarks, so I know what to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Buy no longer supports the SPARQL endpoint and it is not currently available publicly. It was last updated in 2013. RIP https://twitter.com/BBYMetis

Comment: That something I missed! Do you know what the background of this decision was?

Comment: It was an alpha and we lost funding. In the next 2 weeks or so there will be a blog post on [our blog](https://developer.bestbuy.com/blog) talking about the full story, including any next steps. Until then you can get in touch with the developer tweeting to @BBYMetis.

Comment: Sorry about that! In the meantime, you could reach out directly to the creator Jay Myers @jaymyers on Twitter.